# Uninstall old version before installing new

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS, however I want to make checkup of existing installed older versions while installing the new one. I made this exactly like I found here - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new But because I need to check were the old version is installed to make uninstallation correctly,  I added InstallLocation registry value to the installation progress.

If I use ExecWait '$R0 _?=$INSTDIR' and the installation folder of the old version is the same as INSTDIR, everything works perfectly. But if I use ExecWait '$R0 _?=$R1' it gives me NSIS installer error, but I just can't find where is the problem, what have I done wrong?

Can someone help please?
Thanks

---

Registry is added by this:

---

```
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${AppName}" "InstallLocation" '"$INSTDIR"'
```

The code of function:

---

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM \
 "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${AppName}" \
 "UninstallString"

  StrCmp $R0 "" done

MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION \
    "${AppName} is already installed. $\n$\nClick OK to remove the \
    previous version or Cancel to cancel the installation." \
IDOK uninst
Abort

;Run the uninstaller
uninst:
   ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM \
   "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${AppName}" \
   "InstallLocation"

    ClearErrors
    HideWindow
    ClearErrors
    ExecWait '$R0 _?=$R1'
    BringToFront

done:
functionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the `InstallLocation` path with quotes, don't do that or strip off the quotes in your code before executing the installer...

Comment: I am sorry, but could you tell me where exactly should I remove those quotes? I don't understand.

Comment: '"$INSTDIR"', either in the WriteRegStr call or with strcmp+strcpy after ReadRegStr